# Continuous loading of time series data into partitioned folder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, partitioning

I have some incoming data which gets refreshed every hour. So, every hour I receive current measures from different meteorological stations. What I do is to stage it first, so it looks something like this:

```
- 2023-07-28
   - hour=0.xml
   - hour=1.xml
   - hour=2.xml
   - ...
   - hour=23.xml
 - 2023-07-29
   - hour=0.xml
   - hour=1.xml
   - hour=2.xml
   - ...
   - hour=23.xml
```

So, every *.xml file has nothing in common with the others. It is just another moment measures. I have a process which collects all of the xml files currently available and for each(intentionally) of them:

1. Create a PySpark dataframe
2. Do some small transformations on the columns
3. Partition it and write it to a data lake

> df   .repartition(1,'YEAR','DATE')   .write   .mode('append')
> .partitionBy('YEAR', 'DATE')   .parquet(PATH_TO_MY_DATALAKE_FOLDER)

Each of my source files / dataframes has the following structure:

```
['YEAR','DATE','HOUR','METEOSTATION_ID', 'MEASURE-1', , 'MEASURE-2', , 'MEASURE-3']
```

I use the `.mode('append')` command because there might be cases I should enrich existing partition (Example, for the date 2023-07-28 I have a partition which stores data up until 5PM but 6PM data has arrived on the staging).

So, the ultimate goal is after a file was successfully process, I move it to another folder and it doesn't get considered anymore.

I expect on the target (partitioned) side to have something like this:

```
YEAR=2023/DATE=2023-07-28/[ALL_HOURS_FOR_ALL_METEOSTATIONS].PARQUET
YEAR=2023/DATE=2023-07-29/[ALL_HOURS_FOR_ALL_METEOSTATIONS].PARQUET
```

as here, `ALL_HOURS_FOR_ALL_METEOSTATIONS`, is supposed to be a single file which eventually gets updated when new hours data arrives for the same day.

What happens at the moment is that when I run the process for the folders:

- 2023-07-19 (data for 16 hours - 16 xml files)
- 2023-07-20 (data for 23 hours - 23 xml files)
- 2023-07-21 (data for 24 hours - 24 xml files)

On the target I get the following:

- YEAR=2023

  - DATE=2023-07-19

    - 16 parquet files
  - DATE=2023-07-20

    - 22 parquet files
  - DATE=2023-07-21

    - 23 parquet files

**NOTE**: Target folder is empty at the beginning
**NOTE**: Combining all the files in a single DF and loading them is not an option at the moment.

Comment: You said "I expect on the target (partitioned) side to have something like this:...".   Is that what your question is, how to remove successfully processed files, so they won't be considered any more, and how to take one batch of files and  convert it to a single parquet file?  If yes, I think you should post as two questions.  And say what the use would be of the files you are saving.  My instinct is to ask "why not leave files in source as received?" and get rid of second question... which of course means processing would need to pick previously unprocessed.